# PHP/MySQL Critical section

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, critical-section

I'm using PHP with PDO and InnoDB tables.

I only want the code to allow one user-submitted operation to complete, the user can either cancel or complete. But in the case that the user posts both operations, I want one of the requests to fail and rollback, which isn't happening right now, both are completing *without exception/error*. I thought deleting the row after checking it exists would be enough.

```
$pdo = new PDO();

try {

    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $rowCheck = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=99")->rowCount();

    if ($rowCheck == 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("Row isn't there");

    $pdo->exec("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 99");

    // either cancel, which does one bunch of queries. if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) ...
    // or complete, which does another bunch of queries. if (isset($_POST['complete'])) ...
    // do a bunch of queries on other tables here...

    $pdo->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    $pdo->rollback();

    throw $e;

}
```

How can I make the cancel / complete operations a critical section? The second operation MUST fail.

Comment: Wouldn't you just commit it from within your if statements? And roll back through an else?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear, but when the user submits both operations, it would be done in separate requests, but at the same time.

Comment: If you need to synchronize access to that part of code may be you need to check Mutexes. But Mutexes allows 1 thread to access that code block. Ref: [Mutex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mutex.php)

Comment: try using `select for update`, that should lock that particular row until you're finished with it

Comment: Does it take 2 web pages to communicate with the user?  You _cannot_ start a transaction in one web page and `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` it in another page.

Comment: @RickJames  No it doesn't. Intended functionality is that the user submits one of two buttons, and in this case the code works perfectly. In the case where the user submits both buttons in quick succession (both operations delete the row in `table` and depend on it, I want one operation to succeed and the other to fail).

Comment: I've just seen that starting a transaction turns off auto commit, so if one requests deletes the row in `table`, the second request would still see the row in `table` if the other request hasn't called `COMMIT`, so in effect I guess my check to see if the row exists is useless?

Comment: Easiest way: just disable the buttons with javascript after a submit. Make JS a requirement so the user can't disable it and submit the form. Two other thoughts come to mind: temporary tables or SESSIONs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, with one exception:  Add `FOR UPDATE` to the initial `SELECT`.  That should suffice to block the second button press until the first `DELETE` has happened, thereby leading to the second one "failing".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

> Note Locking of rows for update using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` only applies
>   when autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with
>   `START TRANSACTION` or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is
>   enabled, the rows matching the specification are not locked.

Comment: If you perform a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and then a normal `SELECT` on a different connection *IT WILL NOT BLOCK*

Comment: It is as if that 'normal' `SELECT` happened _before_ the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.  So there is no big deal?  Multiple connections are allowed to see different values -- this is part of "transaction isolation" and "MVCC" = _Multiple Version Concurrency Control_.

Comment: You _must_ have a multi-statement transaction for what you are doing.  Hence `autocommit=1` is not sufficient.

Comment: When I first read this solution I was under the impression it would block all reads until this transaction completes its write, which is not the case. Other connections are blocked from writing, and they're blocked from reading if they have the `FOR UPDATE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution just for completeness:

```
private function getLock() {
    $lock = $this->pdo->query("SELECT GET_LOCK('my_lock_name', 5)")->fetchColumn();

    if ($lock != "1")
        throw new RuntimeException("Lock was not gained: " . $lock);
}

private function releaseLock() {
    $releaseLock = $this->pdo->query("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('my_lock_name')")->fetchColumn();

    if ($releaseLock != "1")
        throw new RuntimeException("Lock not properly released " . $releaseLock);
}
```

[MySQL GET_LOCK() documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)