# Test-and-set Int in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `Credit`, that will decrement by a certain amount on some specific action (API Call). However, I need a test-and-set behavior, meaning an atomic test-if-greater-than-amount-to-be-decremented and then decrement it on success, else fail if lower than that amount.

This atomic behavior is important, since many API Calls may hit at the same moment, and if I simply first do a `SELECT Credit` and then an `UPDATE` I might miss some decrement... How can this behavior (which is almost exactly as test-and-set in CPUs) be exhibited on MySQL 8.0?

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269871/213136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Credit = IF(Credit > 10, Credit - 1, Credit)
WHERE id = ?;
```

Hypothetically, if you want to decrement only `Credit` values greater than 10, this would do so. If the `Credit` is already 10 or less, it would not change the value.

After the UPDATE, test for "rows affected" (read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count):

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

ROW_COUNT() returns 0 if the preceding UPDATE resulted in no change. In other words, if it ended up setting `Credit = Credit` because it evaluated the "else" part of the IF() expression.

How can you be sure you won't run into race-conditions? InnoDB locks the row before updating it. Only one session at a time will hold the lock on that row, and it will hold its lock until it commits its transaction.

So a session that has been waiting for the lock won't acquire the lock until the previous holder of that lock commits. The new holder of the lock will see the updated value of `Credit` once it has been committed.